# $f(n) = \sum_{d|n, d < 50}^{n}{d}$ and d is prime

Tags: number-theory, functions

Given that $f(n) = \sum_{d|n, d<50}^{n}{d}$ and d is prime.
So, $f(12) = 2 + 3 = 5, f(101) = 0$
Then find $\sum_{n = 1}^{99}{f(n)}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it's $$S=a_22+a_33+\dots+a_{47}47$$ where for each prime $p≤47$ we define $a_p$ to be the number of multiples of $p$ less than or equal to $99$.  Thus $$a_p=\lfloor\frac {99}p\rfloor$$ Thus $$S=\sum_{p\;prime\;p<50} \lfloor\frac {99}p\rfloor p$$ The list of primes in question is $$\{2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47\}$$ and the corresponding $a_p$ are $$\{49,33,19,14,9,7,5,5,4,3,3,2,2,2,2\}$$

Barring computational error (sadly possible) we get $S=1368$.